# Is data duplication unavoidable here?

Tags: database-design, mongodb

basically I have a list of posts, and I am wondering if I need a separate collection of links to those posts.
Of course I want to show the postname in my abbreviated list (and on mousehover the content too), but querying for the postname and content would load
all comments too right? (because they are embedded. The comments array is expected to be significantly larger than the post 'Content')

Is there any way I can avoid getting another collection but at the same time avoid loading the comments
each time I want to know the name/description of a post?

```
> db.Posts.find()
{ 
  "_id" : "123",
  "Name": "test",
  "Content": "wooops", 
  "comments" : [ {comment1}, {comment2}, {comment3} ]
}
```

Of course, I am aware that I can just create another collection for the comments. But as far as I can tell that won't be possible in production use, because I expect to have a lot of posts each day, which means that each new post would create a new comments collection. Is this recommended? As far as the [official docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections) say, the max collection number is 12000. Even though it says that the number can be increased, I get the strong feeling that this wouldn't be a good idea. 
edit: I calculated it, the absolute maximum is 1.5million collections/=posts. Which is not enough of course.

Any experiences on this matter would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I don't really understood why you dont have "1" collection for all comments named : "comments". (And put a post_id in it so you can get the post's comments.

Comment: @frail: You mean put all comments of all posts into the same collection? My comments are structured as a tree, (I do it as described here: [offical doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-MaterializedPaths%28FullPathinEachNode%29) I figured (I'm new to databases) that querying for the tree structure would be very slow since it's like fishing in a huge bucket, and whenever I need to find any comment, mongodb has an overhead of every other comment in existance on my db.

Comment: If you don't like @frail's suggestion, you can also have the separate comments collection, but all comments for the same post in the same document (same structure as now, just move the comments field into a different collection, with the same post _id).

Comment: @Thilo: Well I think it's obvious now what I need to do. Get a second collection like you suggested here. I'll still ask the mailing list how mongodb handles skipping embedded stuff specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but querying for the postname and content would load all comments too right?

Not necessarily. MongoDB lets you load partial documents (similar to a projection in SQL, where you SELECT only some fields) To do this, you add a second argument to the find() query, supplying a document that lists the elements to be returned:

```
> db.Posts.find({}, {Name:true, Content:true})
```

Comment: Do you have a link to official documentation for that feature? That sounds perfect but I can't find it described anywhere.

Comment: It is in the tutorial. Search for "partial". http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial

Comment: Right, but that doesn't say how it gets loaded into memory. It might still load the whole thing, but just return a partial set. Look here for example: http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2010-03/msg01271.html

Comment: MongoDB is supposed to be able to efficiently skip-scan over the unnecessary fields, pulling out only the required data. That was the main reason for introducing BSON. Unless you have an index on these two fields, it will still have to skip through the whole collection (with an index it could be quite efficient). See my comment on your answer about how you could partition the comments into a separate collection.